# How to communicate between fragments in a deep nested chain?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface

I am trying to better understand the interplay of interfaces, Activities, and Fragments.

According to [this link from the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

They give this example:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

How does this change if you're dealing with a nested chain of Fragments?

For example, let's say I had an Activity, which contained a Fragment, and then that Fragment contained another Fragment, etc. To be explicit:

```
Activity --> Fragment1 --> Fragment2 --> Fragment3 --> Fragment4 --> Fragment5
```

I am trying to understand the accepted best practice for doing the following:

**Let's say Fragment5 has an EditText and a Button with an OnClickListener attached to it. I press the button and the contents of that EditText are somehow sent to a function in Fragment3.**

My question:

I assume that we need to define an interface/listener in Fragment5 like in the example up top, which means the Activity way back in the front should implement that interface, because according to the documentation, Activities should be passing around information between Fragments.

But now, from this Activity, how do we pass the information to Fragment3?

Comment: use `Bundle ` to transfer data when you replace old fragment with new fragment `setArguments` will help you in it.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi That isn't related to my question -- I'm not asking about the Factory pattern. I'm asking about how you'd transfer information from a child fragment up a few parents.

Comment: You can use a third party library like Otto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is saying about sibling fragment to fragment communication. They should communicate through the parent activity.

For child fragment to parent fragment communication, you can directly communicate.

```
((ParentFragment) getParentFragment ).doSomething();
```

You can have a interface, let the parent fragment implement it. Then the child fragment can communicate to the parent fragment through the interface, without directly communicating to another fragment.

Comment: But then doesn't this mean the child fragment is assuming that it's being contained by a parent fragment (as opposed to a parent activity), violating the principles of modularity?

Comment: For sibling parents, Activity controls the fragments. Activity is the direct parent to all sibling fragments. So we can route the data from one fragment to another fragment. It is not feasible in the case of nested fragments. Activity has no knowledge about its child's child fragments.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways I would prefer [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) for this.